# C# WPF read data from TI tm4c123gxl micro controller

Tags: c#, wpf

I do have WPF application that has a live graph. I need to connect my board which is ti tm4c123gxl to my C# application that reads data from the board and put it on the graph. I do not want to use serial communication. I already run the USB_dev_bulk example from Texas instrument resource. so when I connect the board to pc it shows as a Generic bulk Device in device manager not comport. so I need a library or something to use for C# in order to communicate with generic bulk device. any idea ?

Comment: USB uses a two layer driver.  One driver for USB and second for specific type of device.  See sample code (2nd from bottom) on following : https://www.ti.com/tool/download/SW-EK-TM4C123GXL?force_isolation=true

Comment: I don't have any problem with driver. it's already installed and working. my question is using C# and have communication with device as generic bulk device.

Comment: Did you look at sample could at link?